# substract one element of NX1 matrix with another

Tags: arrays, matlab, subtraction

I have the following nX1 matrix, here n is very large, I want to carry out the following operation- (2nd term) minus (first term) ,that is (2.25555-1.45656),(4.74096-2.25555),(440.0000-4.74096) and so on.... for the remaining 'n' number of rows

> 1.45656
>   2.25555
>   4.74096
>   440.00000
>   0.02000
>   550.7
>   0.268

I have done the following, but it is giving only one value

```
[n,m]=size(a)
for i=1,n
    delta_g12(i)=(g_12(i+1)-g_12(i));
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest, Matlab-like way is using a built-in function called `diff`:

```
 delta_g12 = diff(g_12);
```

---

But your way is also possible. Your code is almost correct, the error is in the first line:

```
  for i=1,n
```

The interpreter ignores the `,n` and acts as if you wrote:

```
  for i=1
```

Instead, you should use the colon operator:

```
[n,m]=size(a)
for i=1:n
    delta_g12(i)=(g_12(i+1)-g_12(i));
end
```